# Spinner not reacting to user

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm trying to get a spinner to react to user input however, when I press on one of the items, nothing happens. I'm not getting any errors in the IDE or during run time so I have no idea what I've done wrong. Can anyone help?

```
public class settings extends AppCompatActivity implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
String selected;
int themeno;
String [] themes = {"Green with blue (Default)", "Green with red", "Green with orange", "Green with yellow", "Green with green", "Green with pink", "Green with purple"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    themeno = sharedPref.getInt("Theme", 1);

    Spinner themeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    if(themeno == 1){
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        themeSpinner.setSelection(1);
    } else if (themeno == 2){
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme2);
        themeSpinner.setSelection(2);
    } else if (themeno == 3){
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme3);
        themeSpinner.setSelection(3);
    } else if (themeno == 4){
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme4);
        themeSpinner.setSelection(4);
    }  else if (themeno == 5){
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme5);
        themeSpinner.setSelection(5);
    } else if (themeno == 6){
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme6);
        themeSpinner.setSelection(6);
    } else if (themeno == 7){
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme7);
        themeSpinner.setSelection(7);
    }



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(settings.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , themes);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    themeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Theme selected. Colours will change when you close settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    if(selected == "Green with blue (Default)"){
        editor.putInt("Theme", 1);
        toast.show();
    }

    if(selected ==  "Green with red"){
        editor.putInt("Theme", 2);
        toast.show();
    }

    if(selected == "Green with orange"){
        editor.putInt("Theme", 3);
        toast.show();
    }

    if(selected == "Green with yellow"){
        editor.putInt("Theme", 4);
        toast.show();
    }

    if(selected == "Green with green"){
        editor.putInt("Theme", 5);
        toast.show();
    }

    if(selected == "Green with pink"){
        editor.putInt("Theme", 6);
        toast.show();
    }

    if(selected == "Green with purple"){
        editor.putInt("Theme", 7);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to add a listener to your spinner. Add this line of code inside `onCreate` method:

```
themeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Next, `==` operator is returning `false` inside of all `if` statements.

You should use `.equals()` method to compare Strings. The `==` operator checks if the objects are referring to the same memory location. In your case, `selected` variable and `"any of strings in if statement"` are not referring to same object or memory.

On the other hand, `.equals()` will compare the actual content of variables. Therefore, you are getting false by `if` statement and none of the code inside is executed.

```
if("Green with blue (Default)".equals(selected)) {
    editor.putInt("Theme", 1);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. I added the toast.show(); before the if statements to see if they were the problem but it didn't even show that so I think the method just isn't being called but I don't know why.

Comment: @zakwoolley not sure if it will work but can you try to change the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` ? Also, check with `Log.v` if the `onItemSelected` is getting called

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I've checked and I don't think onItemSelected is getting called.

Comment: Can you check using `Log` if the `onItemSelected` is called or not and then let me know? Also, try to check on other devices or emulators

Comment: No, it's not getting called. I've tried on other devices and it's still not getting called.

Comment: @ZakWoolley I have editted my answer. You have forgotten to add a listener to your spinner. Take a look at my updated answer